# Adding a storyboard above the UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have to present a View Controllers view on top of my UIWebView,

My View Controllers are embedded in a Navigation Controller, Hence first when I did this,

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" andBundle:nil]
ViewController *v = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"]
UIView *addView = v.view
[self.webView.superview addSubView:addView]
```

But this crashed when my view opened and I pressed the button that should navigate me to the other View Controller as I was only presenting the View Controller's view not the navigation property.

Now I am doing this,

```
sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
cameraNavigation = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNavigationController"];
cameraFirstController = cameraNavigation.childViewControllers[0];
UIView *addView = cameraFirstController.view;
[self.webView.superview addSubview:addView];
```

But this gives me a an error as follows

```
<UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency> child view controller:
<ViewController: 0x193e3100> should have parent view controller:
<MainViewController: 0x14e754c0> but actual parent is:
<UINavigationController: 0x193e2c20>
```

Comment: Add your view to ViewControllers view where your webView is added and use [self.view bringSubViewToFront: viewToBeMovedFront] or [self.view insertSubview: aboveSubview:];

Comment: I am adding my ViewControllers view only on the webview

Comment: You are adding it on webView's superView, instead add to the ViewControllers view as mentioned in my first comment.